# Can Keras not add an array of numbers, yielding a scalar?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246565/averaging-over-the-batch-dimension-in-keras/55249513?noredirect=1#comment97252232_55249513), but is a little bit simpler.

I want Keras to be able to take an array of numbers and sum them.  The array should have an arbitrary length, defined by the batch dimension.

The following simple example doesn't work:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras import backend as K

inp = Input(shape = (1,))
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x))(inp)
m = Model(inp, out)

m.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         (None, 1)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)            ()                        0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The output shape should be a scalar: `(1)`.  No batch dimension. `m`, as defined above, doesn't compile.

The desired outcome would be `m.predict(np.array([1,2,3]))` yielding `6`.  Or maybe an array or tensor containing `6`.

Can this basic task -- applying as function over the batch dimension and returning a scalar -- be done in Keras?  If not, could it be done in pure tensorflow?

EDIT:  I just learned that you can predict from this model without compiling it:

```
m.predict(np.array([1,2]))
```

yields

```
array([3., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

I guess my question is now how I can squeeze this into a scalar, and get it to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.reduce_sum()` with `axis=None`. It will reduce over all dimensions:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

inp = Input(shape = (3,))
out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=None))(inp)
m = Model(inp, out)

m.predict(np.array([[1, 2, 4]])) # array([7.], dtype=float32)

m.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            ()                        0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params:
```

Comment: The output is still the same dimension as the input!  `m.predict(np.array([1,2, 4]))
` yields `array([7., 7., 7.], dtype=float32)`.  Also it doesn't compile...

Comment: No, you're wrong. Take a look now. + Are you using `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Comment: Ah, the difference is that you specified the batch size, rather than the second dimension.